# Log4j 2 - Deactivate drools logger

Tags: java, logging, drools, jbpm, log4j2

I  am using [Log4j 2](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) and I am unsuccessfully trying to change the logging level of [jBPM/Drools](http://www.jbpm.org/), having it as a reference. The drools class that keeps logging is [ExtensibleXmlParser](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/drools/blob/master/drools-core/src/main/java/org/drools/core/xml/ExtensibleXmlParser.java).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Root>
        <Logger name="org.drools.core.xml.ExtensibleXmlParser" level="off">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

If I get it right, `ExtensibleXmlParser` uses slf4j and Log4j is compatible with sl4j.

Why doesn't this Log4j configuration work? Could someone provide me a working configuration? Should I configure jBPM/Drools logger indendently?

Comment: Check your classpath: logback-* should not be there, and the bridge from sfl4j to log4j 2 should be there. Or just switch from log4j 2 to Logback (which is probably better anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When log4j seems to ignore your tweaks to the `log4j.properties/xml` file, it most often means you're not fiddling with the right file. It is likely that there is another configuration file in your classpath that gets found earlier and is taken into account.

Search your entire classpath for `log4j*` pattern and see what comes out (include the contents of .jar files and application server /lib and /ext folders, if any).

> If I get it right, ExtensibleXmlParser uses slf4j and Log4j is compatible with sl4j.

"Is compatible" is not equivalent with "is configured to use". SLF4J plugs into appropriate logging framework through the `org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder` class. Search the classpath (best in your IDE) to see what library this class came with. If there is no such class, then SLF4J logs nothing.

Comment: Do you know how I could search my classpath? I am using Eclipse

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+T to find classes, Ctrl+Shift+R to find other files ("resources"). Note that it it is only an approximation of the final runtime classpath.

Comment: Thank you. As Geoffrey De Smet had also suggested, I should be more careful. I had a reference to the log4j2 library, but this is not enough. As soon as I added a reference to the log4j-slf4j implementation bridge, as clearly stated [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-slf4j-impl/index.html) everything started to work normally.